# WebView and external links

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, webview, windows-phone-8

I can't find an answer for such case:

I have a WebView in my application, and i load there HTML that i got from the server - this work fine. But like all HTML pages they have links on other sites. How can i make WebView open external links in Phone Browser?

Here is my callback:

```
<div style="font-weight:bold;"><p style="text-align: justify;">No 6. līdz 17. jūlijam Kazaņā, Krievijā notieko&scaron;ajā XXVII Pasaules vasaras Universiādē Latvijas komandu pārstāvēs 23 Rīgas Tehniskās universitātes (RTU) studenti, kas būs lielākā pārstāvniecība starp Latvijas augstskolām.</p></div><div><p style="text-align: justify;">Latviju vērienīgajā sporta pasākumā &scaron;ogad pārstāvēs rekordliels dalībnieku skaits -120 sportisti no dažādām Latvijas augstskolām. Kopumā pasākumā piedalīsies 162 valstu komandas ar 10 442 sportistiem, sacen&scaron;oties 351 sporta veidā. Tas ir vairāk nekā Londonas Olimpiskajās spēlēs izdalītie 302 medaļu komplekti.</p><p>http://www.google.lv</p>
```

I do something like this:

```
string callback = HttpRequest...
WebView.NavigateToString(callback );
```

Is there some sort of property to open external links on my callback page?

**EDIT:**

I have this on my page:

```
<phone:WebBrowser Name="ArticleContent" />
```

and in C# i'm doing:

```
ArticleContent.NavigateToString(callback);
```

In my callback (HTML string) there are also hrefs ( links to other pages in internet ).
How to make links open in External Phone Browser, **not in my App**

**EDIT 2.0:**

Thanks to Toni Petrina
I have next code now:

```
private void ArticleContent_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
        //webBrowserTask.Uri = new Uri(e.Uri.ToString(), UriKind.Absolute);
        //webBrowserTask.Show();
        webBrowserTask.URL = e.Uri.ToString();
        webBrowserTask.Show();
    }
```

It opens Phones browser and navigates to the page - this part is OK.
When i use back button to return to my app and click on another link in WebView it opens the page in WebView - **HOW IS THAT?** ( this appears on 2 or 3 or 4 clicking on a link, all times randomly ).

EDIT 3.0:

Forgot to cancel the event:
e.Cancel = true;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `WebControl`, and not `WebView`. You can navigate to a URI using the `Navigate` method. See more on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/ff403407%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

EDIT:

For opening a link in external (built-in) browser, use `[WebBrowserTask][2]`. Use it like this:

```
var task = new WebBrowserTask
{
    task.Uri = new Uri(...)
}
task.Show();
```

You can capture outgoing link navigation via the `[WebBrowser.Navigating][3]` event. Simply cancel the current navigation and call the task from above.

Comment: You don't get the point, i have added an edit, maybe this will help to understand me

Comment: But, it works for first time. When i use back button - to return back in my application and select other link it opens page in my WebView

Comment: Forgot to cancel the event: e.Cancel = true; Ooops :)